# Maven Resolver always downloads maven-metadata.xml from remote repositories

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

I am currently working on a project that has a built-in library loader for maven dependencies.

This is my current code:

```java
public class ResolverTest {
    
    private static final File LOCAL_REPO_DIR = new File("localRepo");
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, DependencyResolutionException {
        downloadLibraries(
            Arrays.asList(
                "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
                "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
            ),
            List.of("commons-io:commons-io:2.12.0-SNAPSHOT")
        );
    }
    
    public static List<URL> downloadLibraries(List<String> repositories, List<String> libraries) throws DependencyResolutionException, MalformedURLException {
        // setup connection
        var locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
        locator.addService(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
        locator.addService(TransporterFactory.class, HttpTransporterFactory.class);
        
        var repoSystem = locator.getService(RepositorySystem.class);
        
        var session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();
        session.setChecksumPolicy(RepositoryPolicy.CHECKSUM_POLICY_FAIL);
        session.setUpdatePolicy(RepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_NEVER);
        session.setLocalRepositoryManager(repoSystem.newLocalRepositoryManager(session, new LocalRepository(LOCAL_REPO_DIR)));
        session.setTransferListener(new LoggingTransferListener());
        session.setReadOnly();
        
        List<RemoteRepository> remoteRepos = new ArrayList<>();
        
        var repoIdx = 0;
        for (var repoUrl : repositories) {
            remoteRepos.add(new RemoteRepository.Builder(String.valueOf(repoIdx), "default", repoUrl).build());
            repoIdx++;
        }
        
        remoteRepos = repoSystem.newResolutionRepositories(session, remoteRepos);
        
        // download libraries
        var request = new DependencyRequest(
            new CollectRequest(
                (Dependency) null,
                libraries.stream().map(library ->
                    new Dependency(new DefaultArtifact(library), null)
                ).toList(),
                remoteRepos
            ),
            null
        );
        
        var results = repoSystem.resolveDependencies(session, request).getArtifactResults();
        
        var urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
        for (var result : results) {
            urls.add(result.getArtifact().getFile().toURI().toURL());
        }
        
        return urls;
    }
    
    private static class LoggingTransferListener extends AbstractTransferListener {
        
        @Override
        public void transferInitiated(TransferEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Init transfer " + event.getResource().getRepositoryUrl() + event.getResource().getResourceName());
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```kotlin
implementation("org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:3.8.6")
implementation("org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-connector-basic:1.7.3")
implementation("org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-transport-http:1.8.2")
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that every time the program is restarted and the library loader is called again, the resolver tries to download the `maven-metadata.xml` file of the dependency from all repositories that didn't have it in the previous attempt.

This only seems to happen with snapshot dependencies.

In the example above I'm also using `RepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_NEVER`. If it is set to `RepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_ALWAYS`, the resolver pulls the metadata from all repositories (like it should).
So why is it still pulling from the other repos, even if `UPDATE_POLICY_NEVER` is set?

Setting the session to offline mode (`session.setOffline(true);`) also doesn't work: The maven resolver throws a DependencyResolutionException: `org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact (path to artifact) has not been downloaded from it before.` (The dependency is in my local repo, but wasn't downloaded from central)

Comment: would you mind providing reproducible example? I recently have spent some time on resolving maven puzzles and may help. Hint: `The dependency is in my local repo, but wasn't downloaded from central` is caused by "enhanced local repository" misfeature and could be resolved by providing `-Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true` system property

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Updated the issue with a reproducible example. Also added some more info: This only seems to happen with SNAPSHOT dependencies and the resolver doesn't pull from all repositories, but only those which didn't have the artifact in the previous run.

Is it possible to use the system properties you mentioned with the maven resolver api? I tried setting them with ``System.setProperty()`` and ``session.setSystemProperty``, but it seems to be ignored. (Also tried it with the offline property whose effects should be clearly noticeable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```java
// this one prevents maven from downloading metadata.xml
// if I understand properly it tries to find maven-metadata-0.xml
// in local repository and in case of failure tries remote repositories
session.setResolutionErrorPolicy(new SimpleResolutionErrorPolicy(true, false));

// this one prevents maven from creating _remote.repositories files
// in local repository, yours: in my local repo, but wasn't downloaded from central
session.setLocalRepositoryManager(repoSystem.newLocalRepositoryManager(session, new LocalRepository(LOCAL_REPO_DIR, "simple")));
```